# Coin change leetcode in python

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search, knapsack-problem, coin-change

I tried to solve on my own the LeetCode problem [322. Coin Change](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/):

> You are given an integer array coins representing coins of different denominations and an integer amount representing a total amount of money.
>
> Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.
>
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.

I seem to have a bug and cannot figure it out.

I am solving with DFS, basically saying when the target hits 0, just gather all the `num`s in an array and dynamically keep the shortest possible result. This is the decision tree for the problem:

[image]

This is my solution:

```
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:      
        def dfs(remainder):
            if remainder<0:
                return None
            if remainder==0:
                return []         
            shortest_combination=None
            for num in nums:
                print("target",remainder)
                print("num",num)             
                result=dfs(remainder-num)
                if result!=None:                    
                    combination=[*result,num]                    
                    if shortest_combination==None or len(combination)<len(shortest_combination):                        
                        shortest_combination=combination                    
            return shortest_combination       
        return -1 if dfs(target)==None else len(dfs(target))
    
        
    
s=Solution()
s.coinChange([1,2,5],100)
```

I print `num` and `remainder`, and I see that for some reason `remainder` never hits 0. Based on DFS, if I keep subtracting 1 from 100 I should be reaching 0, but somehow it does not reach it with any `num`.

Comment: I think the problem is that your algorithm is way too slow.  You will, eventually, hit 0, but it will take you a long, long time to get there.  You are looking at *every* possibility of 1 coin, and then *every* possibility of two coins, and then *every* possibility of three coins.  If, for example, you had 10, 5, and 1, just for a depth of three you will look at 1 + 3 + 9 + 27 possibilities.  See better solution in the answers.

Comment: This is the Change Making Problem, a type of knapsack problem. You are trying to solve this with a brute-force combinatorial search, which will return the correct answer when properly implemented, but is too slow for most uses (including Leetcode).

Comment: As a better example of why your algorithm is failing.  Imagine converting 200 to coins using 1, , 2, 5, 10, 25. You will look at every possible combination of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 coins before you look at any combination of 8 coins.  That close to 100,000 combinations, most of which aren't even distinct.

Answer (score 0):

This problem needs to be solved using dynamic programming.  Given any `value`, assume you've already calculated the smallest number of coins to generate 0, ... `value - 1`,  To calculate the smallest number of coins for `value`, look at the number of coins needed for `value - coin1`, `value - coin2`, `value - coin3`, ..., pick the smallest, and add one.

Actually coding this is something you should do on your own.

Comment: Frank! I see the solutions all over the internet for this problem but I am trying to solve leetcode problems in my own ways rather than memorizing the details of solutions of others. I think I implemented very good logic but there is a subtle bug and I could not figure out

Comment: I just added a comment to your original code.   Your algorithm is fine, but massively inefficient.  It is duplicating its calculations over and over, and the deeper you get into the tree, the more it is duplication.  1 + 5 and 5 + 1 both take me to the same place in the same number of coins.  I don't need to investigate both [1, 5 ...] and [5, 1, ...]

Comment: Dynamic programming is one way to solve it, but hardly the only way and not nearly the fastest.

Comment: @RBarryYoung.  It was the first thing that came to mind, and would certainly be fast enough to satisfy LeetCode.

Comment: Yes, it is fast enough for leetcode (which is awful).  It is not true, however, that “it needs to be solved using dynamic programming”.

Comment: So did we answer your question?  Your algorithm is fine.  It just has really bad asymptotic behavior.  A simple solution to get a pretty good speedup is to require that each time you add a new coin, it needs to be the same or smaller than the last coin you added.  You don't need to look at every permutation of your coins.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is correct, it really *does* hit 0, but in that case you don't print it (function exits before printing). Adding more debugging you'll see it does reach that base case and backtracks and correctly identifies the sub-solutions.

The problem really is that the tree you are visiting with DFS is exponentially large, whereby you solve the same problem a multitude of times. If you add a few lines of code to implement memoization, you'll see it does the job:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        memo = {}  # used for memoization
        def dfs(remainder):
            if remainder in memo:  # already solved this problem?
                return memo[remainder]  # then return what we got last time
            if remainder<0:
                return None
            if remainder==0:
                return []         
            shortest_combination=None
            for num in nums:
                result = dfs(remainder-num)
                if result!=None:
                    combination=[*result,num]
                    if shortest_combination==None or len(combination)<len(shortest_combination):
                        shortest_combination=combination                    
            memo[remainder] = shortest_combination  # memoize this solution
            return shortest_combination

        return -1 if dfs(target)==None else len(dfs(target))


s=Solution()
print(s.coinChange([1,2,5],100))  # 20
```